# Insert Value into adjacent column based on conditional statment

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of two columns [Consolidated SKU] and [GAP SKU] I wanna use a For Loop as well as If statement to check each value of GAP SKU and see if its in Consoludated SKU. If it is then in the adjacent cell so a third column [True/False] it will insert True or False. What I have so far is this

```
for x in df['GAP SKU']:
     if x in df['Consolidated SKU']:
```

I just dont know how to access the adjacent column.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: 1) No, you don't want to use a for loop. Looping and pandas are pretty much never the right answer.

Comment: 2) What do you mean by "`GAP SKU` is in `Consolidated SKU`", do you mean if `GAP SKU` is in ANY value of the `Consolidated SKU` column, or do you mean if it's in the `Consolidated SKU` of the same row?

Comment: 3) Please include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) | [Pandas MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)